# How to change structure of mysql result array.?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i want to change my mysql query result array structure. because i have to use that array in line chart of my project.

here is my array structure

Thanks in advance.

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date] => 2017-05-02 00:00:00
        [visitor_count] => 0
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date] => 2017-05-03 00:00:00
        [visitor_count] => 2
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date] => 2017-05-04 00:00:00
        [visitor_count] => 4
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date] => 2017-05-05 00:00:00
        [visitor_count] => 0
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date] => 2017-05-06 00:00:00
        [visitor_count] => 0
    )

[5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date] => 2017-05-07 00:00:00
        [visitor_count] => 0
    )

[6] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date] => 2017-05-08 03:59:52
        [visitor_count] => 1
    )
)
```

i have to convert this result like this

```
[["2017-05-08",0],["2017-05-07",0],["2017-05-06",0],["2017-05-05",0],["2017-05-04",0],["2017-05-03",0],["2017-05-02",0]]
```

Comment: So run `foreach` and create what you need.

Comment: hii.. i have complete this step ... foreach loop

Comment: what can i do ..next

Comment: please...give example

Comment: the idea was that YOU would give an example, show your `foreach` loop. This forum is for help on getting code to work, so you can learn from it and become better at coding. Not for supplying code on demand.

Comment: Hire a freelancer to write code for you.If you want learning or to solve this problem just google it you will find tons of solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_map`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to change the structure of your array.

For example:

```
<?php

$data = array_map(function ($value) {
    return [
        $value->date,
        $value->visitor_count
    ];
}, $dbdata);
```

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is correct. You only need to remove the visitor count, so it will be like this:

```
$result = array_map(function ($data) {
          return [
             $data->date
            ];
          }, $arr);
```

Comment: He needs the visitor count as well.